# Is this made with css?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-transitions

can anyone help with this animation i want to learn how it`s made here is link
http://courses.cssanimation.rocks/p/level-up

Thank you!

Comment: You mean the soft fade-in of the text and its background?

Comment: i mean in background is like building a website from boxes,how i can do that?

Comment: It's done with JS + CSS.

Comment: although that's a mix, you can do that sort of thing in pure css if you want to. Codepen is a great resource to see the sort of things you can do with css animation (and how to do them)

Comment: but how ,can you guys give me some advice or something?Thanks!!

Comment: for that website example. I think it's using js too for a bit timing for each panel. but, if you really want, like @Orangesandlemons said, it can be done using pure css. for me, the first time I learn css animation is from this https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ (reading the code myself, it really helps). try to learn how "transform" work first, then learn how keyframe works https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp